# Byte array from backend is converted to something else on front-end

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

```
[Route("encrypted")]
[HttpGet]
public sbyte[] Encrypted()
{
    var mm = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test\\" + "fill.txt");
    sbyte[] sbt = new sbyte[mm.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(mm, 0, sbt, 0, mm.Length);
    return sbt;
}
```

when I hover over with mouse it shows following bytes (which is correct):
[image]

But when I check on the front-end (javascript). It becomes a different arrayBuffer:

[image]

Here is the front end code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/api/encrypted/', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; //i have tried without this line too
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log("received from server--------");
        console.log(e.currentTarget.response);
        console.log("received from server-------");
    }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Why are you using `sbyte` when reading a file? You should just use `byte` because `ReadAllBytes` returns a `byte[]` not a `sbyte[]`.

Comment: yeah I know. I did without signed bytes and the distortion happens with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not ask a specific question, but I think this might help.

Your controller action is responding with JSON. Dumping `json` to the console shows the same array values on the front-end as does dumping `sbt` to the console on the back-end. Here is the front-end code that dumps the values.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/api/values', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log("json");
        const json = e.currentTarget.response;
        console.log(json);
        console.log("json");
    }
};
```

So, you're sending a JSON array.

As an aside, here are some links about the `arraybuffer` response type.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: LOL good catch. I decided to dump the response bytes into `String.fromCharCode()` and I start getting `"[-55,65,38,-32,-61..."`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just thought it was funny that the controller was JSON serializing a byte array, and I was impressed you noticed that.

Comment: Thank you. You can call me eagle eyes.

Comment: Although your answer didnt not help me go from backend byte array to Arraybuffer in front end, I have accepted your answer. I already tried creating customoutputformatter to get around the json issue, still no luck. Something tell its the characterset of the file that is the issue. For anyone wondering, here is the encrypted file im trying to transport from backend to frontend. http://20secquiz.com/fill.txt - I am unable to load this file into ArrayBuffer in Javascript, it just becomes wrong.